# How can I access public media using instagram api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am only able to see my own post,I am currently doing this

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/blueskies/media/recent?access_token=##########
```

How can I get public media posted by other user with hashtag #blueskies

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the new Instagram Graph API to get hashtag public content:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api

(The API you are using will be deprecated soon and will not work.)

Using Instagram Graph API, its a 2 step approcah, you have to first get hashtag_id using the hashtag_search API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/hashtag-search

```
graph.facebook.com/ig_hashtag_search?user_id={USER_ID}&q=blueskies
```

This will give hashtag_id and then you can get recent or top hashtag media using the hashtag API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/hashtag/

```
graph.facebook.com/{HASHTAG_ID}/recent_media?user_id={USER_ID}&fields=id,media_type,comments_count,like_count
```

Comment: What is USER_ID in this?

Comment: Has anyone even found an answer for this yet im struggling so much to get the USER_ID :(